# Rango de fechas higchart laravel

Tags: laravel, highcharts

Estoy utilizando laravel 6.0 con highchart y quiero mostrar en una grafica la cantidad de computadoras registradas todos los meses seleccionando un año por el usuario, hasta ahora solo muestro la cantidad de computadoras de todos los meses pero sin sellecionar un año 
Controlador

```
$Enero= Computadora::whereMonth('created_at', date('01'))->count();
    $Febrero= Computadora::whereMonth('created_at', date('02'))->count();
    $Marzo= Computadora::whereMonth('created_at', date('03'))->count();
    $Abril= Computadora::whereMonth('created_at', date('04'))->count();
    $Mayo= Computadora::whereMonth('created_at', date('05'))->count();
    $Junio= Computadora::whereMonth('created_at', date('06'))->count();
    $Julio= Computadora::whereMonth('created_at', date('07'))->count();
    $Agosto= Computadora::whereMonth('created_at', date('08'))->count();
    $Septiembre= Computadora::whereMonth('created_at', date('09'))->count();
    $Octubre= Computadora::whereMonth('created_at', date('10'))->count();
    $Noviembre = Computadora::whereMonth('created_at', date('11'))->count();
    $Diciembre = Computadora::whereMonth('created_at', date('12'))->count();

    $chart = new ComputChart();
    $chart->labels(['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr','May','Jun','Jul','Agos','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dic']);
    $chart->dataset('Computadoras registradas en 2019', 'line', [ $Enero,$Febrero,$Marzo,$Abril,$Mayo,$Junio,$Julio,$Agosto,$Septiembre,$Octubre,$Noviembre,$Diciembre ])->color('green')
        ->backgroundColor('#90EE90');


    return view('grafica/anual',compact('chart'));
```

Vista

```
   <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center ">
            <div class="col-md-4">

                    {!! $chart->container() !!}
                    {!! $chart->script() !!}

            </div>
        </div>
```

En el navegador
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Pero quisiera que el año sea dinamico, para que el usuario obtenga los datos del año que el seleccione, lei que tenia que hacerlo con una funcion javascript pero no se como seria

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con `whereYear` ejemplo:

```
$Enero= Computadora::whereYear('created_at', '2019')->count();
```

Si deseas un mes en especifico de ese año sería:

```
$Enero= Computadora::whereYear('created_at', '2019')
              ->whereMonth('created_at', date('01'))->count();
```